# Python - Group by dates

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, time

looking to speed up this task .... it works, just slowly.

```
 #split csv file into two groups.
    for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(row["date"], '%Y-%m-%d')
        if date_time_obj <= datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-03-11", '%Y-%m-%d'):
            group = "before"
        else:
            group = "after"
        df.loc[index, "group"] = group
        df.loc[index, "month"] = date_time_obj.month
    
    ans=[y for x, y in df.groupby('group', as_index=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To speed it up you can do it in a vectorized form (without `iterrows`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-03-08', '2020-03-14')})
df['group'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) <= pd.to_datetime('2020-03-11')
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month

df
```

Output:

```
        date  group  month
0 2020-03-08   True      3
1 2020-03-09   True      3
2 2020-03-10   True      3
3 2020-03-11   True      3
4 2020-03-12  False      3
5 2020-03-13  False      3
6 2020-03-14  False      3
```

Answer (score 0):

MUCH quicker. Thanks. In the end I used:

```
df['group'] = tqdm(pd.to_datetime(df['date']) >= pd.to_datetime('2020-03-11')) 
df.loc[df['group'] == True, 'group'] = "After"
df.loc[df['group'] == False, 'group'] = "Before"
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month

ans=[y for x, y in df.groupby('group', as_index=False)]
```